# Python - Get percentage based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to evaluate '`percent of number of releases in a year`' as a parameter of popularity of a genre in the movieLens dataset.
Sample data is shown below:

[image]

I can set the index to be the year as

```
   df1 = df.set_index('year')
```

then, I can find the total per row and then divide the individual cells to get a sense of percentages as:

```
df1= df.set_index('year')
df1['total'] = df1.iloc[:,1:4].sum(axis=1)
df2 = df1.drop('movie',axis=1)
df2 = df2.div(df2['total'], axis= 0) * 100
df2.head()
```

[image]

Now,what's the best way to get % of number of releases in a year? I believe use 'groupby' and then heatmap?

Comment: do you want to do this :  total_films_released_in_year * 100 / total_films

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clearly use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'movie':['Movie1','Movie2','Movie3'],  'action':[1,0,0], 'com':[np.nan,np.nan,1], 'drama':[1,1,np.nan], 'year
':[1994,1994,1995]})

df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df.set_index('year')
print((df.groupby(['year']).sum()/len(df))*100)
```

**Output**:

```
         action        com      drama
year                                 
1994  33.333333   0.000000  66.666667
1995   0.000000  33.333333   0.000000
```

Also, you can  use `pandas` built-in [`style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) for the colored representation of the dataframe (or just use `seaborn`):

```
df = df.groupby(['year']).sum()/len(df)*100
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='viridis')
```

**Output**:
[image]

Comment: this is awesome.. I was at the groupby statement.. Didn't think about "/len(df)... thnks!!